# Can't load nor refresh routes with dynamic id's

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router

My Dynamic Matching Route is not working on load nor refresh.
I know the problem has been adressed many times, I still don't find a fixing answer.

I have implemented dynamic matching route following the official vue documentation. I have configured my vue-router to be in History mode and as I use an Express/Node.js server, I added connect-history-api-fallback middleware to my server. It's working when I click through a router-link but when I load the URL or refresh the page, instead of my page to be loaded (http://localhost:8080/admincourse for this exemple), I have got these error messages in the console :

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/admincourse/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

GET http://localhost:8080/admincourse/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my front router file and my node server app.js file :

router.js

```
import Home from '../components/Home'
import AdminCourse from '../components/AdminCourse.vue'
import NotFound from '../components/404.vue'
import AdminMedias from '../components/AdminMedias.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/admincourse/:level',
      component: AdminCourse,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        requiresAdminAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/adminmedias',
      name: 'adminmedias',
      component: AdminMedias,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        requiresAdminAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      component: NotFound
    }
  ]
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
require('./../db/mongoose')
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

var app = express()

app.use(history())
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: What response is being returned by `http://localhost:8080/admincourse/main.css`? Do you get a css content? What is the mime type in the response header?

Comment: In fact, there is no such things as main.css nor main.js and I have a `Cannot GET /admincourse/main.css` response